# Record the value in the field through RTTI

Tags: delphi

We need to create a class using rtti with preset values. The values are taken from the attribute. All seems fine works exactly the time when you need to add value in the field. Find the right property and gets the value of the attribute is true. But the record is not operated. Tell me where wrong?

```
program DemoGenerator;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Rtti;

Type
  // My attribute
  DemoDataAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
  private
    FGenerator: String;
  public
    constructor Create(Generator: String);
  published
    property Generator: string read FGenerator write FGenerator;
  end;

  // 
  TSomeType = Class
  private
    fPhone: string;
  published
    [DemoData('+1800764328')]
    property Phone: string read fPhone write fPhone;
  End;

  // 
  TMegaSuperClass = Class
    Function Go<T: Class, constructor>: T;
  End;

Procedure Test;
var
  LMsc: TMegaSuperClass;
  New: TSomeType;
Begin
  LMsc := TMegaSuperClass.Create;
  try
    New := LMsc.Go<TSomeType>;
    Writeln('New.Phone: ' + New.Phone);
  finally
    LMsc.Free;
    // New.Free;
  end;
End;

{ DemoDataAttribute }

constructor DemoDataAttribute.Create(Generator: String);
begin
  FGenerator := Generator;
end;

{ TMegaSuperClass }

function TMegaSuperClass.Go<T>: T;
var
  LContext: TRttiContext;
  LClass: TRttiInstanceType;
  LProp: TRttiProperty;
  LAttr: TCustomAttribute;
  LField: TRttiField;
begin
  // Init Rtti
  LContext := TRttiContext.Create;
  LClass := LContext.GetType(T) as TRttiInstanceType;
  Writeln('LClass: ' + LClass.ToString);
  // Result
  Result := T.Create;
  for LProp in LClass.GetProperties do
  begin
    Writeln('LProp: ' + LProp.ToString);
    for LAttr in LProp.GetAttributes do
    begin
      Writeln('LAttr: ' + LAttr.ToString);
      if LAttr is DemoDataAttribute then
      Begin
        Writeln('Attr value: ' + DemoDataAttribute(LAttr).Generator);
        // How write value?
        LProp.SetValue(@Result, DemoDataAttribute(LAttr).Generator);
      End;
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    Test;
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

end.
```

Console output:

> TSomeType
>   property Phone: string
>   DemoDataAttribute
>   value: +1800764328
>   Phone:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
LProp.SetValue(Pointer(Result), DemoDataAttribute(LAttr).Generator);
```

The first argument to `SetValue` is declared as `Instance: Pointer`. A class reference is simply the pointer to the instance, which is what you want.

Comment: I think that the cast to `Pointer` is necessary, but cannot check right now.

Comment: The cast is necesary (won't compile otherwise). Also you can cast like this: `TObject(Result)` and it works too. The thing is I really don't understand why such casting is needed given that the compiler could figure it out with the current constraints on the generic (shouldn't class and constructor constraint imply a TObject descendant?)